# LINQ Update one list from another

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find an elegant way of updating values in a ConcurrentDictionary. I've created a quick example of what I'm trying to achieve below:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyDataClass> dataLookup = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, MyDataClass>();

// Initialise the example dataLookup with some dummy data
new List<MyDataClass>
{
    new MyDataClass { Id = 1, ValueProperty = 0 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 2, ValueProperty = 0 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 3, ValueProperty = 0 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 4, ValueProperty = 0 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 5, ValueProperty = 0 }               
}.ForEach(myClass => dataLookup.TryAdd (myClass.Id, myClass));

// incoming results that need to be fed into the above dataLookup 
List<MyDataClass> newDataReceived = new List<MyDataClass>
{
    new MyDataClass { Id = 1, ValueProperty = 111 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 3, ValueProperty = 222 },
    new MyDataClass { Id = 5, ValueProperty = 333 }
};
```

So in the above example I want to set the ValueProperty in the dataLookup ConcurrentDictionary with the Id of 1, 3 & 5 to 111, 222 and 333 respectively. I can change the newDataReceived object into anything I want but I'm pretty much stuck with the dataLookup as a ConcurrentDictionary.

At the moment I'm iterating through the list but I'm looking for some suggestions on using LINQ to make this task more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's truly just *updates* that are coming in, you could just use another `ForEach`:

```
newDataReceived.ForEach(x => dataLookup[x.Id].ValueProperty = x.ValueProperty);
```

Personally I would just express this with a simple foreach loop though:

```
foreach(var update in newDataReceived)
    dataLookup[update.Id].ValueProperty = update.ValueProperty;
```

Note that above is missing a check whether the item is actually contained in the concurrent dictionary - if that is not guaranteed (it's not an update) you would have to add this check.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to update in Join() and surprised it worked.
You obviously have to implement your own IEqualityComparer in order to compare only required members such as ID, key or similar.

```
    private static void SaveProcessedFile(IEnumerable<HashedRow> processedRows, IEnumerable<HashedRow> justProcessedRows)
    {
        var comparer = new HashedRowEqualityComparerOrderLine();
        var updated = justProcessedRows.Join(processedRows, n => n, o => o, (n, o) => { o = n; return n; }, comparer); // n - new, o - old
        var inserted = justProcessedRows.Except(updated, comparer);
        // To do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq is for querying, not updating.  If you were able to create a new dictionary it would be possible by using Linq's `ToDictionary()` method, but since you have to call a method to add you're more or less relegated to a `foreach` loop.

Also, Linq wouldn't make anything *more efficient*, it just makes the code look more natural.