# Is there a C# LINQ alternative for the following loop?

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say Foo has a public field 'Child' of type Bar, I have an list of Foo with a given size, and I have a list of Bar with the same size.

Would there be a more efficient way to assign the children to the parents by using Linq, instead of the snippet provided?

```
for (int i = 0; i < parents.Count; i++)
{
   parents[i].Child = children[i];
}
```

Comment: If `parents[i].Child = children[i];` then there is no need to assign and that's pretty efficient :)

Comment: In what way "more efficient"? In terms of CPU cycles your approach is fine and certainly not less efficient than any LINQ way.

Comment: If you want to use LINQ then look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109663/linq-update-one-list-from-another) however a for loop may be just as efficient

Comment: Raises the question why you have two lists of objects which depend on each other in the first place. Why dont you have only one collection and initialize the `Child` property where you load it(for example from the database)?

Comment: Also, LINQ is for basically for selection, not processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop visits each *parent* once so it is O(n) in Big-O notation.

You cannot get better than O(n) if you have to visit each element.

I would conclude that there is no more efficient way.

#### Do you have to do it?

If it's always true that `parents[i].Child == children[i];` then you don't need to make this assignment at all and just go to `children[i]` if you want a child of `parent[i]`.

Comment: Your last suggestion works only if for any given `Foo`, you always know its index `i` in the array, something not given as true in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: With LINQ you should never try to change the source. LINQ is meant to extract data from sequences into a new sequence.

So in your problem, every Foo has exactly one Bar, identified by the same index. In database terms you would say that this one-to-one relation is implemented by giving the elements the same value for primary key.

You ask whether this can be more efficient. The answer depend on how you will be using this, after you've created the "List of Foos, each Foo with its one-and-only Bar".

If you want to change all original Foos, by adding the Bar of the Foo, then no, it won't get more efficient than this.

However, if you will only be using parts of the results: only some Foos, or only some properties of the Foos and Bars, or maybe sometimes you want it with some properties, and some other times with other properties, then it would be a good idea to think LINQ: keep everything `IEnumerable<...>` as long as possible. This way, if you do other LINQ things, like FirstOrDefault, Any, Select, GroupBy, etc, you won't have filled the complete list with items that you won't use anyway.

The proper LINQ method depends a bit on how you will use this: do you have this only in this specific procedure? Or will you be using this more often with your `Foos` and `Bars`? Maybe you even have other one-to-one relations based on index?

### I only want to use it in this procedure

So you have two lists, equal size, and Bar[12] is the one and only Bar of Foo[12]

Whenever you have two sequences X and Y of equal length, and you want to combine {X[0], Y[0]}, {X[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0), Y[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0)}, etc, consider to use one of the overloads of [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-5.0)

```
List<Foo> foos = ...
List<Bar> bars = ...

var foosWithTheirBars = foos.Zip(bars,

    // parameter resultSelector: get a Foo and its Bar to make one new:
    (foo, bar) => new Foo
    {
        // select only the Foo and Bar properties that you plan to use
        Id = foo.Id,
        Name = foo.Name,

        Child = new Bar
        {
            Id = bar.Id,
            Name = bar.Name,
            ...
        },
    });
```

Now if after this you don't use the complete result, you won't have enumerated more than necessarry:

```
var firstForWithItsBar = foosWithTheirBars.FirstOrDefault();
```

You will have only enumerated Foo[0] and Bar[0]

Or suppose you only want to show it in pages:

```
int pageSize = 24,
int pageNr = 3;
var pageOfFoosAndBars = foosWithTheirBars.Skip(pageNr * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

### I plan to do this with Foos and Bars in several procedures

Consider to create an extension method for Foos and Bars. This way you can use it as if it was a standard LINQ method. If you are not familiar with extension methods. See: [Extension methods demystified](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/csharp/995/extension-methods-csharp)

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Combine<TResult>(this IEnumerable<Foo> foos,
    IEnumerable<Bar> bars,
    Func<Foo, Bar, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return foos.Zip(bars, resultSelector(foo, bar));
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetMyFoos();
IEnumerable<Bar> bars = GetBars();

var result = foos.Combine(bars, (foo, bar) => new
{
    // select the Foo and Bar properties that you plan to use in this situation
    Date = foo.Date,
    FooId = foo.Id,
    FooName = foo.Name,

    BarName = bar.Name,
    ...
})
.Where(combineResult => combineResult.Date.Year < 2000)
.GroupBy(foo => foo.Name)
.Select(...);
```

### No, I want to use it with any sequence

In that case, just use Zip:

```
IEnumerable<Student> students = ...
IEnumerable<Address> addresses = ...

var studentsWithTheirAddress = students.Zip(addresses, (student, address) => new
{
    Id = student.Id,
    Name = student.Name,
    Street = address.Street,
    City = address.City,
    ...
})
```

Comment: "you can never change the source" - that's not true. You generally *shouldn't*, but you absolutely *can*. For example I suspect that: `parents.Select((parent, index) => parent.Child = children[index]).Count();` would actually have the same effect as the loop. I absolutely wouldn't recommend doing it, but I'd expect it to work.

Comment: I would recommend changing "can" to "should" then.